# Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I would love to have help for this.
I have been trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 but have been having the messages below.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`>
```

Here is the content of

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security universe
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb-src http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb-src http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Comment: You have software sources configured for Ubuntu 8.04! If you're actually running 8.04, see [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/22949). If not, but you know why you have these software sources configured, please edit your question to explain. Otherwise, please provide the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (you can paste it into your question and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K; one way to bring up the contents of that file is to run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in a terminal).

Comment: That is a MESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste this into your " /etc/apt/sources.list " file and then run

**This will no-longer include software from hardy** but it will get the job done.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20140204)]/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security universe
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
#deb http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
#deb-src http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
#deb http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
#deb-src http://hu.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirrors.gigenet.com/ubuntuarchive/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I've had similar issues - Oddly I had no problems on machines I upgraded early (before the .1 release) and I have no hardy sources in sources.list... I'll attempt this.